# Hilbert space: Find an orthonormal basis of $V$.

Tags: linear-algebra, hilbert-spaces, orthonormal

I'm working with small exercises about Hilbert spaces and I found this problem, which reminds me about the course Linear Algebra that I took for some years ago. The exercise that I have trouble with,

**Exercise:** Let $H=L^2([0,1],\mu)$ be a Hilbert space, here $\mu$  denotes the Lebesgue measure. We are given three vectors (functions defined on the interval [0,1]), $f_0=1$, $f_1=x$ and $f_2=x^2$.

1. Let $V$ be a subspace of $H$ spanned by $f_0$ and $f_1$. Find an orthonormal basis of $V$.
2. Let $P_V:H\rightarrow V$ be the orthogonal projection from $H$ onto $V$. Find $P_V(f_2)$.
3. Find the distance between $f_2$ and $V$.

Of course I know how to find basis from the core course in Linear Algebra, but I've never seen this type of exercise on this level and therefore I hope I can get some hints and ideas.

Comment: If I work it out right, I guess if you apply Gram Schmidt  $\{1,\frac{x-1/2}{1/12}\}$ is an orthonormal basis for $V$.

Comment: Okay let me try it out and I will be back later.

Comment: Okay I got $x-1/2$ and if I take the norm of $1-x/2$ from 0 to 1, I get $\sqrt{3}/6$. But if I don't take the squareroot, then I get 1/12 as you did. I believe that I should take the squareroot, i.e. $\langle 1-x/2,1-x/2 \rangle^{1/2}$.

Comment: You are right,. A square root is needed

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any idea for the second question?

Answer (score 2):

For an orthonormal basis you don't have to invoke Gram-Schmidt. (And I believe that neither Gram nor Schmidt would have used Gram-Schmidt to determine that basis.)

Take as first element $f_0=1$, which obviously has length $1$ and as second element any straight line for which the area under and over the ordinate is equal (that makes it perpendicular to $f_0$).  An Ansatz would be $a(x-1/2)$. As the integral of $(x-1/2)^2$ is $1/12$ we get $\pm2\sqrt3(x-1/2)$.

You don't need Gram-Schmidt for the projection either. Let $u$, $v$, and $w$ vectors of a Hilbert space.  To find the orthogonal projection of $w$ on the subspace generated by $u$ and $v$ split $w$ in two vectors $w=w^\top+w^\perp$ where $w^\top$ ist the projection and $w^\perp$ is perpendicular to the subspace.  We have
$$
w^\perp=w-w^\top=w-(\lambda u+\mu v).
$$
As $\langle w^\perp,u\rangle =\langle w^\perp,w\rangle=0$ we want to solve the system
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\lambda\langle u, u\rangle +\mu\langle u, v\rangle&=\langle u, w\rangle\\
\lambda\langle v, u\rangle +\mu\langle v, v\rangle&=
\langle v, w\rangle.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
In case $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent, the Gram-matrix
$$
G=\begin{pmatrix}
\langle u, u\rangle &\langle u, v\rangle\\
\langle v, u\rangle &\langle v, v\rangle
\end{pmatrix}
$$
is regular and
$$\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda\\ \mu
\end{pmatrix}=G^{-1}
\begin{pmatrix}
\langle u,w\rangle\\
\langle v,w\rangle
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
In our case $u=f_0=1$, $v=f_1=x$, and $w=f_2=x^2$.  We easily compute
$$\langle u,u\rangle=1,\langle v,v\rangle=1/3,\langle u,v\rangle=1/2,\langle u,w\rangle=1/3, \langle v,w\rangle=1/4, $$
hence
$$G=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1/2\\
1/2 & 1/3
\end{pmatrix}
$$
from where
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\lambda\\ 
\mu
\end{pmatrix}=\frac{1}{1\cdot1/3-1/4}
\begin{pmatrix}
1/3 & -1/2\\
-1/2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
1/3\\1/4
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
-1/6\\1
\end{pmatrix},
$$
that is, $P_V(f_2)=-1/6+x$.

Furthermore, the distance from $f_2$ to $V$ is the length of $f_2-P_V(f_2)=x^2-x+1/6$ which is easily calculated to be $\sqrt{1/180}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints: I am also new to Hilbert Space Theory, but I have some ideas as how to proceed. I give you just hints as per your request.

1. Apply Gram Schmidt to find the orthonormal basis.
2. We need to compute

$$P_V(f_2)=\text{arg}\min\limits_{v\in V}||v-x^2||$$

As every $v \in V$ is a linear combination of basis vectors $p_1,p_2$ found in the previous exercise, we can write $v= \lambda p_1+(1-\lambda)p_2$. Thus

$$||v-x^2||=||\lambda p_1+(1-\lambda)p_2-x^2||$$

This norm could be computed and taking derivative with respect to $\lambda$ and setting to $0$,we get the necessary $\lambda$ and hence the required projection vector can be computed.

3. Distance is $0$ as $f_2 \in V$.

Partial attempts. I hope this helps.

Comment: So $p_1=f_0=1$ and $p_2=\frac{(x-1/2)\sqrt{3}}{6}$?

Comment: Yes, the basis vectors which are obtained before hand.

Comment: Allright I will try to work it out.

Comment: Okay I'm stuck in your calculations of the second exercise. If I compute the derivative w.r.t.lambda and set this result to 0, I don't get anything.

Comment: Do you get a linear function of $\lambda$ upon computing the norm?

Comment: Ah no, I don't obtain a linear function, all I get is a fraction with both lambda and x. I'm not sure I'm doing this correct.

Comment: As you are in $[0,1]$ your $x$ should disappear integrating between limits $0 \to 1$

Comment: True, now I have a linear function after I compute the derivative. I obtained,
$\frac{d}{d\lambda}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{36}-\frac{49}{72}+\frac{145}{72}\lambda$

Comment: Okay since I got $\frac{d}{d\lambda}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{36}-\frac{49}{72}+\frac{145}{72}\lambda$ I solved the equation, i.e. $\frac{d}{d\lambda}=0$ I got ${\frac{53}{580}}-{\frac {8\,\sqrt {3}}{435}}$. How can this be used to compute the projection vector? Thanks in advance

Comment: Substitute in the expression for  $v=\lambda p_1+ (1-\lambda)p_2$

Comment: And that would be my answer? i.e. $v={\frac { \left( 1054\,x-655 \right) \sqrt {3}}{6960}}-{\frac {4\,x}{
435}}+{\frac{167}{1740}}$